# jdbc unicode conversion issue

Tags: unicode, jdbc, character-encoding

My database(Oracle 10g) characterset is set to ISO-8859-6(AR8ISO8859P6) to store arabic characters. 
When I query the database, JDBC Converts the data from the database character set to Unicode.
 Because of this unicode conversion some of the characters are lost(translated to ?)
same behavior for  both oci and thin..

In JAVA Is there any solution  to retrieve the data in  database format(without doing any unicode conversion)?
Is there any driver available retrieve the data from oracle in database format( encoding)?

Thanks

Comment: The transformation from the oracle internal encoding (ISO-8859-6) to the Java encoding (UTF-16) is supposed to be done transparently by the JDBC driver if you use setString/getString. Could you tell us how you detect that some characters are lost?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that any conversion *TO* Unicode can fail. But a conversion *FROM* Unicode to something else might fail. This can be the case when storing back the data or - most likely - on output to some terminal or UI.

If that's not the case: Can you give us some examples for each step?